# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null Error

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an error on my code.

I'm trying to check if the button is on the page if so proceed. The button is not on the page when it loads, but is on a external page that replaces the form after it has been submitted. Then the thank you html page is loaded via ajax.

```
var reloadButton = document.getElementById('reloadPage');

if (reloadButton.length > 0) {

    function reloadPage() {

        location.reload();

    }

    if (reloadButton.addEventListener) {

        reloadButton.addEventListener('click', reloadPage, false);

    } else {

        reloadButton.attachEvent('onclick', reloadPage);

    }

}
```

I understand that if the element if not present you get an error but that why I created a if statement. Should I be checking of the element another way?

Answer (score 0):

reloadButton.length is trying to call a property of something that may or may not be there.  If it's not available, trying to access the property causes the error.  You could simply do:

```
if (reloadButton)
```

Comment: Thanks @kellycode. This fixed my issue as far as getting the error to go away. Now the button won't work because since its an external page that replaces the form with a thank you messages after the form has been submitted its not originally loaded with the document. How do i fix this with out having to add a internal script tag to the thank-you.html that loads and keep my code with my external js file?

Comment: The question doesn't seem clear.  If your form submit is displaying a different "Thank you" page.  It seems that, on your "Thank you" page you don't really want to reload the page, you want to have a link going back to the original page.  Or, you could submit your form with AJAX and never leave the page and simply display a "Thank you" with your success return, which I think is a cleaner approach over form submits, as you never lose state of your page.